# Positioning items inside container

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

I have a mathematical problem that I am trying to solve and want to realize in javascript. 
I have a "space" meaning: a rectangular format. This shall work as a kind of container.
Then I have smaller forms: other rectangular ones and circles.

I need to find out a solution how to calculate how many of these forms fit into the container.

So I kind of need the ideal way, how to stack these items in there.

If it is too many, leaving out some. And if it is too few, stacking them from bottom up.

I am trying to realize this in Javascript but not getting far.

From my vision it should be kind of like this:

```
var items = [circle1,2],[rect1,2,4],[rect2,5,6]]; // array with the forms to put inside container, stating a radius for circle and width/height for rectangles 

var container = [10, 4]; // given the size of the container in width and height. 

function stackItIn (container, items){
// now this is where I am totally lost
}
```

The premium part would be even showing it graphically at the end.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Checkout [packing problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems). There are plenty of links and ideas to get you started there.

Comment: Thank you very much for the direction!

Comment: Looks like a difficult problem in general. Are there any further constraints that could narrow the space of all possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a treemap. Sort the tiles and pick the first and create a node in a tree. Split the tree on both axis and pick the next tile and find the best fit of the nodes.